# Need advise in calculating best ratio

Tags: oracle, plsql

So, I have some table structure with [data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd834/1) (use this link for info)

I need to exlude number of dates(column cnt) one by one from 0 to 10(in example) and also can exclude additional columns that have value 1 in column flag.

And in the end I need to get the highest avarage value of koef based on non excluded values.

Main idea is to get the HIGHEST avg koef, by excluding rows from calculating, based on upper conditions.

Any one have idea how to deal with this task?

Comment: "I need to exlude number of dates(column cnt) one by one" - unclear. Have you tried any query ?

Comment: I have some mechanism, but it's very hard query, and I can't post it here.

Comment: As example for better understanding of question. For example avg koef for 100 rows I have 2.4, and I see that 25-28 rows have koef 1-2. I exclude this rows by updating last column(can_exclude) to 1, and get avg based on excluded rows 2.7.

Comment: i am not clear about 1st exclude. `select (select sum(koef) from dat where can_exclude=0)/(select count(*) from dat where can_exclude=0) AS Average from dual;` Try this query. Add your 1st exclude logic in where clause.

Comment: I hope you understood me :) I need to exclude some rows. It can be pl/sql or just sql query, no matter. And after all manipulation get the best avg koef

Comment: Nigade, yes this query will be used after manipulation with can_exclude column. But how to find needid column to flag as 1 for excluding

Comment: `update dat set can_exclude=1 where KOEF between 1 and 2;`

Comment: thats not a decision, I can update with such query more than 10 posible rows(in this example column cnt). And updated values can be not one by one

Comment: i am not able to get you... `select (select sum(koef) from dat where koef NOT between 1 and 2 and flag!=1)/(select count(*) from dat where koef NOT between 1 and 2 and flag!=1) AS Average from dual;` you can set koef range here that you want to exclude...even without updating rows.

Comment: Ok. Again. A CAN(but don't need) exclude only from 1 to 10 rows from calculating avg value that goes one by one in date. And also CAN(but don't need) can exclude rows where flag = 1. The main idea to get thie HIGHEST avg sum

Comment: you mean to say..yoou can exclude atmax 10 rows ?

Comment: yes, I can exclude max 10 rows(value from column cnt)  that are going one by one based on column date and can exclude additional rows with flag = 1

Comment: in example all values of CNT column assigned to 10 which rows needs to be exclude ?

Comment: You have 100 rows, and y need to exclude from 1 to 10 rows that are going one by one based on date. for example 01/01/1990, 01/02/1990, 01/03/1900 this 3 rows is going one by one, but you can't exclude 01/01/1990 and 01/03/1990 without excluding 01/02/1990. after excluding 10 rows, you can also exclude additional rows with flag = 1

Comment: its gonna be very difficult as there are so many permutation n combinations. first you need to calculate actual avg then needs to check for all combinations of rows(max 10) whose avg is less than actual average. if possible try some different logic. As table rows increases it's complexity will also increases.

Comment: You right. But if you have any helpfull advise how to move one. This will be greate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query looks promising:

```
select * 
  from (
    with 
      data as (select row_number() over (order by m_dt) rn, dat.* from dat),
      numbers as (select level n from dual connect by level<=10)
    select rn, m_dt, n, 0 flags, 
        (select avg(koef) from data where rn not between d.rn and d.rn + n - 1) av
      from data d, numbers
    union all 
    select rn, m_dt, n, 1, 
      (select avg(koef) from data 
          where flag = 1 or rn not between d.rn and d.rn + n - 1) av
      from data d, numbers
      order by av desc)
  where rownum = 1
```

I hope I understood your discussion and clarifications properly, but even if not - maybe some of this code will be useful.
For each date in table query eliminates 1 to 10 consecutive rows and counts `avg` for the rest. 
The same is done also when we add rows with flag=1 to eliminated set. Outer query selects row with highest average.

Here is also PL/SQL version (far from optimal, I just wrote something to check SQL solution results - 
both solutions produced the same best scenario):

```
create or replace procedure miner is
  v_best_avg number := 0;
  v_curr_avg number := 0;
  v_max_cnt number := 10;
begin
  for v_cnt in 1..v_max_cnt
  loop
    for o in (select row_number() over (order by m_dt) rn, dat.* from dat)
    loop
      select avg(koef) into v_curr_avg 
        from (select row_number() over (order by m_dt) rn, dat.* from dat) 
        where rn not between o.rn and o.rn + v_cnt - 1;
      if v_curr_avg > v_best_avg then 
        v_best_avg := v_curr_avg;
        dbms_output.put_line(trunc(v_curr_avg, 4)||' '
          ||to_char(o.m_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' '||v_cnt||' '||'flags not excluded');
      end if;
      select avg(koef) into v_curr_avg 
        from (select row_number() over (order by m_dt) rn, dat.* from dat)
        where flag = 1 or rn not between o.rn and o.rn + v_cnt - 1;
      if v_curr_avg > v_best_avg then 
        v_best_avg := v_curr_avg;
        dbms_output.put_line(trunc(v_curr_avg, 4)||' '
          ||to_char(o.m_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||' '||v_cnt||' '||'flags not excluded');
      end if;
    end loop;

  end loop;

end miner;
```